# How to use SUMIFS function for summing values if criteria range exists in a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My data:

```
A   B    C
a   3    d
b   1    a
c   8    e
d   5
```

I want to use `SUMIFS` function, sum range is `B1:B4`, if the corresponding value in column `A` exists in column `C`, sum the values in column `B`,
in this case the sum will be `3 + 5 = 8`
I tried `=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4, COUNTIF($C$1:$C$3,A1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this;

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,C:C))`

The `SUMPRODUCT` is used to tally the results of the `SUMIFS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can [sumproduct](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumproduct-HP005209293.aspx) the [sumif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx), you don't need [sumifs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A5,C2:C5,B2:B5))
```